# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory

Tags: java, xml, build.gradle

I am new  to Java and Gradle, I am trying to build a simple REST API, here are my dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.7.0'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2'

    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.6.7")
    implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.4.0-b180830.0359'
    implementation 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:4.0.0-M4'
    implementation 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:4.0.0-M4'
}
```

I am receiving the following error:
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory`

I have seen similar  questions but could not find a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JAXB API and implementation versions don't match. [jaxb-core 4.0.0-M4](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-core/4.0.0-M4) depends on [jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api 4.0.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.xml.bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/4.0.0). That's completely incompatible with your JAXB API version. The biggest difference is that your JAXB API version uses the `javax` package prefix and the Jakarta API version uses the `jakarta` package prefix. I'm guessing that Spring wants to use an implementation compatible with the API version you're using (Spring hasn't switched to Jakarta EE 9 yet).

I was checking to see if there was a Spring Boot starter for JAXB or something like that, but I couldn't find any. That means you'll probably need to provide your own implementation. I suggest that you switch to the Jakarta EE 8 version instead: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.xml.bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/2.3.3 for the API, and https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.6 for the implementation. Both are the latest versions that still use the `javax` package prefix.